# Register/Log in using password hash then password verify

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, password-hash

I am creating a PHP function for a page i am creating where I register users and hash their passwords in MYSql database called users.  The registration part works fine and i see the user being created and their passwords being hashed but when i try using the Login.php and using the same password i saved, it doesn't work.  Here's my code i put in my function.php:

```
// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = esc($_POST['username']);
    $password_1 = esc($_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = esc($_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) {  array_push($errors, "Uhmm...We gonna need your username"); }

    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "uh-oh you forgot the password"); }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) { array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");}

    // Ensure that no user is registered twice.
    // the email and usernames should be unique
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password =  password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $user_dir = $_POST['username'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_dir, status, admin)
                      VALUES('$username', '$password', '$user_dir', 'OPEN', 'N')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        // get id of created user
        $reg_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

        // put logged in user into session array
        $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($reg_user_id);

        // if user is admin, redirect to admin area
        if ( in_array($_SESSION['user']['admin'], ["Y", "N"])) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
            // redirect to admin area
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . 'admin/dashboard.php');
           // exit(0);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
            // redirect to public area
          //  header('location: index.php');
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

That works great, the part that doesn't work is this login function for my login.php:

```
// LOG USER IN
if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $username = esc($_POST['username']);
    $password = esc($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username required"); }
    if (empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password required"); }
    if (empty($errors)) {


 Here is the problem--> $password =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // encrypt password

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // get id of created user
            $reg_user_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['id'];

            // put logged in user into session array
            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($reg_user_id);

            // if user is admin, redirect to admin area
            if ( in_array($_SESSION['user']['admin'], ["Y", "N"])) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                // redirect to admin area
              //  header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/dashboard.php');
                exit(0);
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                // redirect to public area
              //  header('location: index.php');
                exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'Wrong credentials');
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that my problem is DEFINITELY this:

```
 $password =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // encrypt password
```

and what i have tried replacing it with is

```
$password = password_verify($password, mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

nothing happens but i know the 2 part of the password_verify function is matching the $password with where it is in the table which i assume is the row (hence trying to use the num_rows).

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This line `$password = password_verify($password, mysqli_num_rows($result);` has many things wrong with it. It has no closing `)` and `mysqli_num_rows` returns the number of rows so you can't definitely use it in `password_verify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `password_verify()` to verify login instead of just the `sql` one.

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $username = esc($_POST['username']);
    $password = esc($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username required"); }
    if (empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password required"); }
    if (empty($errors)) {


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            // get id of created user
            $reg_user_id = $row['id'];

            // put logged in user into session array
            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($reg_user_id);

            // if user is admin, redirect to admin area
            if ( in_array($_SESSION['user']['admin'], ["Y", "N"])) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                // redirect to admin area
              //  header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/dashboard.php');
                exit(0);
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                // redirect to public area
              //  header('location: index.php');
                exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'Wrong credentials');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe change `*` to just `password` since the "Asker" doesn't seem to use other columns.

Comment: Ok this has to work but i may have something wrong because i no longer get a Server error but instead when i try logging in, it just displays "wrong credentials" as if the password is incorrect....

Comment: In database, is the password for the username hashed?

Comment: @hungrykoala do you mean getting rid of " username='$username' " and just leaving it as:  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";  ?

Comment: @Mr.Blue Yes, they all are... For instance, just to make it easier, i just registered Prox, with Password as Prox, and in the Database its hashed as: $2y$10$rk1hlMZZXiZiAI9CMQZXT.9xOTftMAth.RKTACvb/h4pV34teyLgS

Comment: I mean that instead of `SELECT *` you'll use `SELECT password` since this reduce the load for your query as it will only fetch one column instead of getting every column in your table.

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($row);` - after - `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` ?

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: In registration - `password_1` and `password_2` - same value?

Comment: @hungrykoala he's also using column id. And it's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @Mr.Blue it works!  Thanks, all i had to do was change what i had to what you edited:  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";  THANK YOU

Comment: @Mr.Blue that was just a suggestion to help improve the query. Didn't spot `id` there. :)

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi -  Don't escape the password, just pass it directly to password_hash() and password_verify().

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check that the entire hash was stored properly in MySQL. Official documentation on `password_hash()` recommends `varchar(255)`. In most cases, MySQL won't complain if you tried to `INSERT` a hash string that is larger than the column size. It will simply perform a silent truncation and proceed with the `INSERT`.

If your passwword hash was inserted properly, then your original code containing the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1
```

should work.

Comment: Yes i just checked the structure and it the password structure is:    password  varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci